# Netlogo How can I avoid the "dividing by 0" error during the dividing process compiling with Behavior space?

Tags: netlogo, zero, divide

I get an error saying "It is dividing by 0". How can I avoid the "dividing by 0" error during the dividing process compiling with Behavior space of Netlogo? This is a Run-time Error popup message. " It is divided by 0. Error while observer running / Called by procedure GO, Called by button 'go' " The following is sample program. The variable "number-of-stop" means that number of ticks while stopping the turtles stopped on the road, and "number-of-dead" means that the number of dead turtles. Behavior space collects the data by every tick. When the variable is 0, the divide-by-zero error occurs. Are there any ideas? Thank you.

```
globals [ Ans number-of-stop number-of-dead ]

set Ans precision((number-of-stop) / (number-of-dead))3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just set a test before doing the calculation, for example (not tested):

```
set Ans ifelse-value (number-of-dead = 0)
  [ -1 ]
  [ precision((number-of-stop) / (number-of-dead))3 ]
```

This sets the value to -1 if the denominator is 0 and only does the division if the test fails (that is, if number-of-dead is not 0)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The sample code runs in my model without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to this problem is to use `carefully`, which allows you to take an alternate action if an error occurs. It can be useful particularly if there are conditions that could cause and error that are difficult or tedious to check for in advance.

```
globals [ Ans number-of-stop number-of-dead ]
to go
 set number-of-stop 10 
 set number-of-dead 0
 carefully [set Ans precision((number-of-stop) / (number-of-dead))3] [set Ans -1]
 show Ans
end
```

You can also as NetLogo to tell you what the error was, if that is useful.

Comment: Thank you for the another approach. This also run properly. Thank you!